# Download a file with javascript

Tags: javascript, download, zip, bookmarklet

I am creating a bookmarklet that will allow you to download all images from the current page as a zip. I am fine with creating the zip file, but I don't know how to implement the actual download. It would be nice to be able to do it automatically, but from my understanding you cannot invoke a download to the user's downloads folder with JavaScript. Could I create some sort of button or link from which the user can download the file? The zip will be a data stream since I am packaging the images on the fly.

Essentially, I'd like the user to click the bookmarklet, be prompted whether they would like to download the images, and when they click ok, I grab the images, package them, and allow them to download the resulting data as a .zip file.

How can this be done? I'd like to make it one-click-and-done if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create a invisible iframe and provide the url of the zip file.

code goes like this

```
$('body').append('<iframe src="test.zip" style="display: none;" ></iframe>');
```

Comment: what is the url of the zip file if it's a data stream?

Comment: ok...this works if you save the file in server...what code you are using in server??

Comment: I'm not using a server. this is entirely client-side. An example would be downloading all images on a wikipedia page.

Comment: ok....so set that stream as data.....check this "data:application/zip;base64,"+content;

content is the stream...

Comment: or provide this in href link

<a href="data:application/zip;base64,"+content></a>

Comment: can I put "data:application/zip;base64,"+content in the iframe src?

Comment: `'<iframe src="data:application/zip;base64,'+content'" style="display: none;" ></iframe>'`
Like that?